# Websockets Tomcat 7 does not work in existing project

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, websocket, java-websocket

I try to run a websocket server in a Java project that was running on Tomcat6. I have set up a Tomcat 7 server where the project now is running on.
First I tried to run the socket example of Tomcat7. This run perfectly. I copied this class to my old project. When I run the old project again all the functionalities are working like before but only the websocket server doe not work.

This is the ChatAnnotation class that I have copied from the examples from Tomcat to my old project.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArraySet;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

@ServerEndpoint(value = "/websocket/chat")
public class ChatAnnotation {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ChatAnnotation.class);

    private static final String GUEST_PREFIX = "Guest";
    private static final AtomicInteger connectionIds = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private static final Set<ChatAnnotation> connections = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<ChatAnnotation>();

    private final String nickname;
    private Session session;

    public ChatAnnotation() {
        nickname = GUEST_PREFIX + connectionIds.getAndIncrement();
        logger.info("ws instance");
    }

    @OnOpen
    public void start(Session session) {
        this.session = session;
        connections.add(this);
        String message = String.format("* %s %s", nickname, "has joined.");
        broadcast(message);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void end() {
        connections.remove(this);
        String message = String.format("* %s %s", nickname, "has disconnected.");
        broadcast(message);
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void incoming(String message) {
        // Never trust the client
        String filteredMessage = String.format("%s: %s", nickname, message.toString());
        broadcast(filteredMessage);
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable t) throws Throwable {
        logger.error("Chat Error: " + t.toString(), t);
    }

    private static void broadcast(String msg) {
        for (ChatAnnotation client : connections) {
            try {
                synchronized (client) {
                    client.session.getBasicRemote().sendText(msg);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.debug("Chat Error: Failed to send message to client", e);
                connections.remove(client);
                try {
                    client.session.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // Ignore
                }
                String message = String.format("* %s %s", client.nickname, "has been disconnected.");
                broadcast(message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have noting added in my web.xml. In my old project are also tcpsockets used can this be the problem?
Can anyone help me with this problem?

**EDIT**
Class added:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.websocket.Endpoint;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerApplicationConfig;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class ExamplesConfig implements ServerApplicationConfig {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ChatAnnotation.class);

    public Set<ServerEndpointConfig> getEndpointConfigs(Set<Class<? extends Endpoint>> endpointClasses) {
        Set<ServerEndpointConfig> result = new HashSet<ServerEndpointConfig>();
        log.info("getEndpointConfigs");
        return result;
    }

    public Set<Class<?>> getAnnotatedEndpointClasses(Set<Class<?>> scanned) {
        log.info("getAnnotatedEndpointClasses");            
        return scanned;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any class implement [ServerApplicationConfig interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerApplicationConfig.html)? (Like `websocket.ExamplesConfig` class in Tomcat example...)

Comment: yes in the example folder is there an ExampleConfig class but i don't find this is used somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java websocket server use return value of `ServerApplicationConfig interface` to deploy programmatic endpoints and for annotated endpoints.
For Tomcat example, if you change the **package name** of `ChatAnnotation`. You have to modify `websocket.ExamplesConfig` too.

```
public Set<Class<?>> getAnnotatedEndpointClasses(Set<Class<?>> scanned) {
    // Deploy all WebSocket endpoints defined by annotations in the examples
    // web application. Filter out all others to avoid issues when running
    // tests on Gump
    Set<Class<?>> results = new HashSet<>();
    for (Class<?> clazz : scanned) {
        String name = clazz.getPackage().getName();
        boolean ok = name.startsWith("websocket.");
        if (ok) {
            results.add(clazz);
        }
    }
    return scanned;
}
```

The `getAnnotatedEndpointClasses(scanned)` only return classes which package name start with **websocket.** Unmatched classes will not deployed even they have `@ServerEndpoint` declarations.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have added a class ExamplesConfig (see above) but need I somewhere say that the socket server must be started or something because I does not work with adding this class

Comment: Your implementation doesn't return `ChatAnnotation` class. If you do NOT want filte annotated endpoints, `getAnnotatedEndpointClasses(Set<Class<?>> scanned)` can simply return `scaned` variable without change it.

Comment: I have edit it. Now I'm returning `scanned` but connect to the socket server. I try to connect to ws://80.0.0.10:8080/clientserverws/chat. My server is connected on 80.0.0.10 and my application is running on 8080. The webpages of the application can I visit. Also I doesn't see any log from my websocket code of above. Need I start this server or is it running automatically?